# Dataframe with column of strings to column of integer lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where in one column, the data for each row is a string like this:

```
[[25570], [26000]]
```

I want each entry in the series to become a list of integers.

IE:

[25570, 26000]
 ^       ^
 int     int

So far I can get it to a list of strings, but retaining empty spaces:

```
s = s.str.replace("[","").str.replace("]","")
    s = s.str.replace(" ","").str.split(",")
```

Dict for Dataframe:

```
     f =  {'chunk': {0: '[72]',
  1: '[72, 68]',
  2: '[72, 68, 65]',
  3: '[72, 68, 65, 70]',
  4: '[72, 68, 65, 70, 67]',
  5: '[72, 68, 65, 70, 67, 74]',
  6: '[68]',
  7: '[68, 65]',
  8: '[68, 65, 70]',
  9: '[68, 65, 70, 67]'},
 'chunk_completed': {0: '[25570]',
  1: '[26000]',
  2: '[26240]',
  3: '[26530]',
  4: '[26880]',
  5: '[27150]',
  6: '[26000]',
  7: '[26240]',
  8: '[26530]',
  9: '[26880]'},
 'chunk_id': {0: '72',
  1: '72-68',
  2: '72-68-65',
  3: '72-68-65-70',
  4: '72-68-65-70-67',
  5: '72-68-65-70-67-74',
  6: '68',
  7: '68-65',
  8: '68-65-70',
  9: '68-65-70-67'},
 'diffs_avg': {0: nan,
  1: 430.0,
  2: 335.0,
  3: 320.0,
  4: 327.5,
  5: 316.0,
  6: nan,
  7: 240.0,
  8: 265.0,
  9: 293.3333333333333},
 'sd': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: 134.35028842544406,
  3: 98.48857801796105,
  4: 81.80260794538685,
  5: 75.3657747256671,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: 35.355339059327385,
  9: 55.075705472861024},
 'timecodes': {0: '[[25570]]',
  1: '[[25570], [26000]]',
  2: '[[25570], [26000], [26240]]',
  3: '[[25570], [26000], [26240], [26530]]',
  4: '[[25570], [26000], [26240], [26530], [26880]]',
  5: '[[25570], [26000], [26240], [26530], [26880], [27150]]',
  6: '[[26000]]',
  7: '[[26000], [26240]]',
  8: '[[26000], [26240], [26530]]',
  9: '[[26000], [26240], [26530], [26880]]'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
f = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(s, orient='index')
f.columns = ['timecodes']
f['timecodes'].apply(lambda x: [a[0] for a in eval(x) if a])
```

**Output**

```
Out[622]:
0                                        [25570]
1                                 [25570, 26000]
2                          [25570, 26000, 26240]
3                   [25570, 26000, 26240, 26530]
4            [25570, 26000, 26240, 26530, 26880]
5     [25570, 26000, 26240, 26530, 26880, 27150]
6                                        [26000]
7                                 [26000, 26240]
8                          [26000, 26240, 26530]
9                   [26000, 26240, 26530, 26880]
10           [26000, 26240, 26530, 26880, 27150]
11                                       [26240]
12                                [26240, 26530]
13                         [26240, 26530, 26880]
14                  [26240, 26530, 26880, 27150]
15                                       [26530]
16                                [26530, 26880]
17                         [26530, 26880, 27150]
18                                       [26880]
19                                [26880, 27150]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: How could I make this apply in a situation where there are no values in the original string? ie [[]]

Comment: I don't understand this solution and can't get it to work. This is part of a larger df, fyi.

Comment: i am assuming that you have another entry like [[]] in the dict..right.. if thats the case the update should work, i added a check in the list comprehension "if a ".. that should work

Comment: in the dataframe, yes. if my dataframe is 'f' and the column in question is 'timecodes' how should I format your answer?